# Strange behaviour of Parsley.js in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari, parsley.js

so we are working with parsley.js. The problem is, i think is, it's not working cross browser with Safari.

**First Bug:**
I have this `input` where you can only type numbers. It looks like this:

```
input#mtlbeitrag.pull-right(data-type="number", name="vb", value="#{calc.vb}", required="required", min="0")
```

When i now type "1000", what parsley does is make that number too "1.000".
Obviously this is a problem because we are parsing that number into an Integer. So your algorithm parses "1.000", which is supposed to be "1000" to "1.0".

**Second Bug:**
Parsley is ignoring the `require` tag. Not only that the popup-messages are not working and are only displayed as a list-element. No, it also lets the user submit the form with wrong inputs.
[image: On Safari]
[image: On Chrome]

My question is:
Are these well known bugs or did we just implement is the wrong way?
Can anyone confirm this bugs with safari?

On Google Chrome, non of these errors occure.

Also, is there a better, cross-browser library that does the same?

PS: When i do this [test](http://parsleyjs.org/tests/index.html) on Safari, nothing happens.

Comment: Hey, When I run http://parsleyjs.org/tests/index.html on Safari, all is working for me. Could you paste in your post your safari version, and the failing test-suite tests?

Comment: @TimDau you think you can mark the below answer as correct?

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that you are using the HTML5 form validation and forgot to add `novalidate` to the enclosing form tag?
If `novalidate` is not found then HTML5 form validation will take over and overwrite whatever parsley would have done...

I believe in fallbacks so I include this:

```
$("form.js-validate").attr("novalidate","novalidate").parsley();
                       ^
```

That way if JS is not loaded for some reason HTML5 validation will be the fallback.
(Note that in this case you must remove the `data-validate="parsley"` from your form or you just use `$("form.js-validate").attr("novalidate","novalidate")` on load)

Just FYI: The reason Safari fails is because its HTML5 validation is "laggy".

Old question but perhaps some bearded internet traveler will be helped

Comment: This bearded internet traveler was indeed helped. +1 for publishing how you use Parsley with HTML5 fallback. Seems obvious now, in hindsight, but they could really do with clarifying that in their docs.

Comment: Glad this helped! Bearded to bearded that is